# AngularJS: prevent empty (but dirty) form inputs from being included in AJAX post

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a form with an 'Address' section. I send my form data to the server using an $http post request.

If I don't type anything in the address fields (pristine) then Address data is not included in the object data I'm sending to the server.

If I do type something in the address fields, then **delete what I typed** (leaving it blank), empty fields are included in th JSON post to the server:

```
{
    street:"",
    city:""
}
```

I don't want to include the (optional) address data if the fields are blank.

Is there a way to easily reset individual form fields to 'pristine' if they are left blank?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to set something to pristine is manually. That is, once a form has been touched, it's touched until you say otherwise.

I would probably do a check in the update function for values in the form field as well as relying on pristine status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use ng-pattern in order to invalidate your empty fields, which will prevent them from being added to your submitted object. I'd add something like that in the controller

```
$scope.nonEmpty=/^(.+)$/i
```

Then in the HTML

...< input ... ng-pattern='nonEmpty' ... >

If the field is empty it won't be added because it doesn't match the pattern, else it will be sent

Answer (score 0):

You can put a watch on the value, check for empty, then reset it to pristine manually

```
$scope.$watch('inputName',function(newVal){
  if(newVal ==="")
     $scope.form.inputName.$pristine = true;
});
```